# ¿Como guardar qué posts le gustan al usuario?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php7

¿Sí han visto cómo es cuándo le dan corazón y vas a tu session de ususario y te aparecen todos los post que les has dado corazón?
Tengo una tabla de la siguiente forma

```
CREATE TABLE `articulos` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_padre` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`titulo` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`tipo` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`fecha` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`autor` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`extracto` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`texto` TEXT NOT NULL,
`thumb` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=15
;
```

Aún no hago la sesión de ususarios, pero ya hice la de los administradores. Pero quiero que siendo usuario
¿Qué debo añadir o cómo?
El chiste es poder consultar a todos los posts que el usuario le da dado corazón

Comment: La clásica pregunta ¿ **Un** usuario puede tener **varios** posts como favoritos ? Si ¿ **Un** post favorito puede tener **varios** usuarios ? Si... Esto nos daría que necesitamos una relación Muchos a Muchos, una tabla intermedia que contenga el id del post y el id del usuario. Con este esquema solucionarías este tema.

Comment: No, no. El post no es del usuario, es un post que el admin sube y el usuario puede dar corazón

Comment: Hablamos de la relación que existe entre post y "favoritos"/"corazones"/"me gusta" así que da un poco igual quien sea el propietario del post,... La relación en la base de datos es del mismo tipo, Muchos a Muchos.